# Are there disadvantages using proportional features instead of absolute values?

Tags: machine-learning, proportion

I was wondering whether there are disadvantages in using proportional features instead of features with absolute values. For example: I have the following data set, which includes, TV duration, smartphone duration, other activities duration, all measured in minutes.

I can either use the durations as given, or I can compute the proportional duration features, which is simply the duration / total duration (sum of all activities duration).

So I was wondering what the disadvantages are of using proportional features, instead of them just as they are.

PS: I will be using logistic regression and SVM's, but I do not think that really matters for my general question.

Comment: The two options have different meanings. Which to use probably depends on what's most relevant to your problem. 'Fraction of time spent doing X' could be more relevant to some problems, while 'absolute number of minutes doing X' could be more relevant to others.

Answer (score 0):

I think proportions is better for SVM. Reason is you transform your data from minutes, which is unbounded, to variables that fall in [0,1]. As user20160 pointed out, some durations might be significantly larger than others on average. But that's alright. You need one more normalization, this time over the columns. In R,

```
d.bar = rpois(10, 20)
d.bar[1] = 2
d.bar[10] = 4
x = sapply(d.bar, function(.d)rpois(10, .d))
tot = apply(x, 1, sum)
x1 = x / tot
apply(x1, 1, sum) # check
x2 = scale(x1, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```